# Concurrent requests: second request does not recognize updates from the first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, thin

I have an extremely long operation (~30s on average) that happens in a request cycle. It is not a huge deal because it is ran very rarely and only through an administrative portal, otherwise I would push it to Resque or whatever.

When the request starts and the object is not flagged, the first thing that happens in the controller method is to set a flag:

```
def create
  raise if @foo.flag?
  @foo.update_attributes! flag: true
  # perform lengthy operation
ensure
  @foo.update_attributes! flag: false
end
```

When I start the first request, it sets flag to true and begins the operation. Then when I start the second request while the first is hanging, it never raises an error even though I can see clearly in the Rails console that flag is true for `@foo`.

I was under the impression that `update_attributes!` commits the database transaction, and so subsequent requests should see the changes. Is this not the case?

I am just testing in development with the thin server. Is there any way I can do this?